# Gitlab-CI: AWS S3 deploy is failing

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab-ci, aws-cli

I am trying to create a deployment pipeline for Gitlab-CI on a react project. The build is working fine and I use artifacts to store the dist folder from my `yarn build` command. This is working fine as well.

The issue is regarding my deployment with command: `aws s3 sync dist/'bucket-name'`.

Expected: "Done in x seconds"

Actual:

```
error Command failed with exit code 2. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command. Running after_script 00:01 Uploading artifacts for failed job 00:01 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

The files seem to have been uploaded correctly to the S3 bucket, however I do not know why I get an error on the deployment job.
When I run the `aws s3 sync dist/'bucket-name'` locally everything works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [AWS CLI Return Codes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/return-codes.html)

2 -- The meaning of this return code depends on the command being run.

*The primary meaning is that the command entered on the command line failed to be parsed. Parsing failures can be caused by, but are not limited to, missing any required subcommands or arguments or using any unknown commands or arguments. Note that this return code meaning is applicable to all CLI commands.*

*The other meaning is only applicable to s3 commands. It can mean at least one or more files marked for transfer were skipped during the transfer process. However, all other files marked for transfer were successfully transferred. Files that are skipped during the transfer process include: files that do not exist, files that are character special devices, block special device, FIFO's, or sockets, and files that the user cannot read from.*

The second paragraph might explain what's happening.

Comment: `warning: Skipping file 'filename.svg'. There was an error trying to decode the the file 'filename.svg' in directory "../../dist/assets/". `  You are correct, I have however little understanding of what is causing the skip solely in my Continuous Deployment.

Comment: try adding `--debug` flag to the `aws s3` command and see if it shows any additional info.

Comment: Thank you Anton, gitlab was decoding files wrongly.

Comment: Glad that helped! Please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `yarn build` command.  See https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run

Comment: I did do 'yarn build' in the step prior to deployment.

Comment: Okay, and I'm glad you sorted it out!  :)

Answer (score 0):

As Anton mentioned, the second paragraph of his answer was the problem. The solution to the problem was removing special characters from a couple SVGs. I suspect uploading the dist folder as an artifact(zip) might have changed some of the file names altogether which was confusing to S3. By removing ® and + from the filename the issue was resolved.